# python re.split lookahead pattern

Tags: python, regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying re.split to get BCF#, BTS# and LAC, CI from logfile with the header and regular structure inside:

```
==================================================================================
RADIO NETWORK CONFIGURATION IN BSC:
                                                         E P  B
                                      F                  T R  C D-CHANNEL  BUSY
                      AD OP           R  ET- BCCH/CBCH/  R E  S O&M LINK  HR  FR
 LAC   CI         HOP ST STATE  FREQ  T  PCM ERACH       X F  U NAME  ST
                                                                         /GP
===================== == ====== ==== == ==== =========== = = == ===== == === ===

BCF-0010  FLEXI MULTI  U WO                                   2 LM10  WO
10090 31335 BTS-0010  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHAATT070D    BB/- 
                                                                               7
              TRX-001  U WO      779  0 1348 MBCCH+CBCH    P  0
              TRX-002  U WO      659  0 1348                  1
              TRX-003  U WO      661  0 1348                  2
              TRX-004  U WO      670  0 1348                  0
              TRX-005  U WO      674  0 1348                  1
 10090 31336 BTS-0011  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHAATT200D    BB/- 
                                                                               7
              TRX-006  U WO      811  0 1348 MBCCH+CBCH    P  2
              TRX-009  U WO      845  0 1349                  2
              TRX-010  U WO      819  0 1349                  0
              TRX-011  U WO      823  0 1349                  1
              TRX-012  U WO      836  0 1349                  2
 10090 31337 BTS-0012  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHAATT340D    BB/- 
                                                                               5
              TRX-013  U WO      799  0 1349 MBCCH+CBCH    P  0
              TRX-014  U WO      829  0 1349                  1
              TRX-017  U WO      831  0 1302                  2
              TRX-018  U WO      834  0 1302                  1
              TRX-019  U WO      853  0 1302                  0
              TRX-020  U WO      858  0 1302                  2
              TRX-021  U WO      861  0 1302                  1

BCF-0020  FLEXI MULTI  U WO                                   0 LM20  WO
 10090 30341 BTS-0020  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHABYT100G    BB/- 
                                                                               1
              TRX-001  U WO       14  0 1856 MBCCH+CBCH    P  0
              TRX-002  U WO       85  0 1856                  1
 10090 30342 BTS-0021  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHABYT230G    BB/- 
                                                                               1
              TRX-003  U WO        4  0 1856 MBCCH+CBCH    P  2
              TRX-004  U WO       12  0 1856                  0
 10090 30343 BTS-0022  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHABYT340G    BB/- 
                                                                               1
              TRX-005  U WO       20  0 1856 MBCCH+CBCH    P  1
              TRX-006  U WO       22  0 1856                  2
 10090 30345 BTS-0025  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHABYT100D    BB/- 
                                                                               5
              TRX-007  U WO      793  0 1856 MBCCH+CBCH    P  0
              TRX-008  U WO      851  0 1856                  1
              TRX-009  U WO      834  0 1857                  2
              TRX-010  U WO      825  0 1857                  1
 10090 30346 BTS-0026  U WO                                                0   0
 KHAKHABYT230D    BB/- 
                                                                               4
              TRX-011  U WO      803  0 1857 MBCCH+CBCH    P  2
              TRX-012  U WO      860  0 1857                  0
              TRX-013  U WO      846  0 1857                  1
              TRX-014  U WO      844  0 1857                  2
              TRX-015  U WO      828  0 1857                  0
              TRX-016  U WO      813  0 1857                  1
 10090 30347 BTS-0027  U WO                                                0   2
 KHAKHABYT340D    BB/- 
                                                                               5
              TRX-017  U WO      801  0 1352 MBCCH+CBCH    P  2
              TRX-018  U WO      857  0 1352                  0
              TRX-019  U WO      840  0 1352                  1
              TRX-020  U WO      838  0 1352                  0
              TRX-021  U WO      836  0 1352                  1
              TRX-022  U WO      823  0 1352                  2
              TRX-023  U WO      821  0 1352                  0
              TRX-024  U WO      817  0 1352                  1

=======================================================================================
```

with code:

```
def GetTheSentences(infile):
    with con:
       cur = con.cursor()
       cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eei")
       cur.execute("CREATE TABLE eei(BCF INT, BTS INT PRIMARY KEY) ")
    with open(infile) as fp:
        for result_1 in re.split('BCF-', fp.read(), flags=re.UNICODE):
            BCF = result_1[:4]
            for result_2 in re.compile("(?=BTS-)").split(result_1):    
                rec = re.search('TRX-',result_2)
                if rec is not None:
                    BTS = result_2[4:8]
                    print BCF + "," + BTS
```

I need to split result_1 in BTS-related parts including 13th characters before "BTS-" ("10090 31335 BTS-0010") using regex lookahead and split to result_3 for each TRX but have no success.

Please support!

Answer (score 8):

Python's [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) doesn't split on zero-length matches.

Therefore `re.compile("(?=BTS-)").split(result_1)` will never split your string. You need to find a solution without `re.split()` or use the new [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

Comment: But BTS = result_2[4:8] getting BTS ID from BTS-xxxx and it looks like "BTS-" has been left in result_2 by "(?=BTS-)". Could you please specify what zero-lenght matches means?

Comment: `(?=BTS-)` matches a *position* between two characters, specifically, the position right before the string `BTS-`. It doesn't match any actual characters, though; that's why the match is always zero characters long. It's a quirk of the Python regex engine not to consider this as a valid splitting point. Other regex engines don't have this restriction.

Comment: @Superbest: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that the regex should be compiled using the `(?V1)` option? As in `regex.compile("(?V1)(?=BTS-)").split(result_1)`?